# Nuxt + Vuetify Cannot read property 'email' of null`

Tags: vue.js, input, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, two-way-binding

I get an error when trying the `v-model` two way binding on the Vuetify `v-text-field` in Nuxt.
I don't know why I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null` as soon as the text field gets an input.

Could someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-vuetify-v-model-binding-u0xte?file=/components/MailWindow.vue) because I really don't understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `this.email` and `this.message` inside brackets in this v-window-item

```
<v-window-item :value="3">
 <v-card-text>
    <h3 v-if="email">
      Your mail address : <a>{{ this.email }}</a>
    </h3>
    <!-- throws error -->
    <p v-if="message">{{ this.message }}</p>
    <!-- also throws error -->
  </v-card-text>
</v-window-item>
```

You have to use `email` and `message` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Could you explain why it only throws the error when the field receive an input, please ?

Comment: Because you have used the directive v-if. This way <h3> and <p> are not present when email or message is empty.